# postgresql: pg_ctl status shows no server running when the server is running as a windows service

Tags: postgresql, windows-services, windows-administration

I have PostgreSQL 9.4(not installed, rather self configured) which is also installed as a Windows service. Now I am trying to check the status of the server using `pg_ctl.exe status -D data_dir_path`, but it only shows the status when I start the console as admin.

My final goal is to be able to shutdown/ start the database server without admin rights. Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL so that I can start/stop the servers locally without admin rights?

As far I read in the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html), the services can be registered to a user using `[-U username] [-P password]` arguments but I am not sure whether this is the database user or the local windows user. I tried registering the service using the following code but it does not install it. And I do not see any logs too. The commnd follows:

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N service_name -U database_user -P database_user_password -D data_dir_path -S auto -o "-p port"
```

Thanks in advance