# Why does pg_ctl status says no server is running, when one actually is?

Tags: windows, postgresql, server

**Issue** 
I have installed postgresql 14 on Windows 11, as per these [instructions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/).
I configured it so the database server running on the background runs on port 5432.
Using psql and pgAdmin, I am able to connect to that server, and I can see it running in TaskManager -> Services.

As such, I would expect running `pg_ctl status` to return confirmation of that, but all I am getting is "no server running", even when I explicitly specify the data directory with the -D option.

**Things I've tried checking** 
I have checked the data directory by running
`select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';` 
The result of that is: C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data

also running running echo `echo $PGDATA` in my Git Bash terminal returns
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data

As such, the default argument for -D of pg_ctl status is that directory if my understanding is correct, but also specifying the path explicitly returns the same result: `pg_ctl status -D "$PGDATA"`

I have found the same issue on a few other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355216/postgresql-pg-ctl-status-shows-no-server-running-when-the-server-is-running-as) one, but none of the answers fit my case. If anyone knows, or can see where I'm misunderstanding something from my explanation, please tell me.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps the user that runs `pg_ctl status` is lacking crucial permissions...

Comment: Those are not the official instructions.

Comment: Can you add a listing for that directory?

Answer (score 0):

**Open a Windows CMD shell in Administrator mode, then type:**

cd c:\program files\postgres\12\bin

pg_ctl status -D "c:\program files\postgresql\12\data"

**You should see:**

pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 5684)